# How to count values with different where clauses on the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, grouping, medoo

I hate that I have to ask but I just cant handle it.

I have this table `votes`:

[image]

`type=1` is an upvote, `type=0` would be a downvote

I want this output:

```
[
  {'video': 'best-of-mehrwert', 'upvote': 2, 'downvote': 0},
  {...}
]
```

I am using medoo:

```
<?php
$votes = $database->query(
  // 'SELECT COUNT(video) as votes, video FROM votes GROUP BY video, type'
  '
    SELECT video,COUNT(*) as counts
    FROM votes
    GROUP BY video,type;

  '
)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($votes);
```

which gives me

```
[{"video":"anlaesse","counts":"1"},{"video":"best-of-mehrwert","counts":"2"}]
```

How do I "add a column" like "upvotes" i.e. entries where type = 1 and the same with type = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easiest to `SUM` up a 1 for each row where your criteria matches:

```
SELECT 
    video, 
    SUM(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as upvotes,
    SUM(CASE type WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as downvotes 
FROM 
    votes
GROUP BY 
    video;
```

Note, you should omit `type` from the `GROUP BY` in order to get a single row back for each video.

Comment: thats cool! it works, thanks a lot. any notes on performance? is there maybe a medoo inbuilt function for this?

Comment: Performance shouldn't be a problem, but it would be hard to say without knowing your table definition and what index(es) you already have, and the size of this table over time. I can't speak to medoo.

Answer (score 2):

two variants:

```
select
  video,
  sum(case when type=1 then 1 else 0 end) as upvote,
  sum(case when type=0 then 1 else 0 end) as downvote
from votes
group by video
```

and

```
select
  video,
  sum(type) as upvote,
  sum(1-type) as downvote
from votes
group by video
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c73f2a/5

Comment: the second one does not seem to work, i dont get an error, just `Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean`

Comment: probably medoo cant handle it :/

Comment: @Alex medoo has nothing to do with sql execution

Comment: @Alex I've fixed typo

Comment: could you explain what `then 1 else 0 end` does?

Comment: yep, the `,` was it :)

Comment: @Alex are you kidding? we're calling sum function, so we have condition if something then 1 else - what should we summarize? 0, so we put 0 in else

Comment: And with mysql another variant is `sum(type=1) as upvote, sum(type=0) as downvote`

Comment: is there a special name for this sort of functionality in sql?

Comment: @Alex aggregation probably?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `case` expression to count only the type of votes you're interested in:

```
SELECT   video, 
         COUNT(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) as upvotes
         COUNT(CASE type WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) as downvotes
FROM     votes
GROUP BY video, type;
```